# Microservice:Rest Template versus Client Jar

Tags: java, microservices, resttemplate

I  have a microservice which is responsible  for giving cached data over the rest end points. I have 2 big projects which need this microservice.

My confusion is, if i should  use restTemplates to call the rest end points or use the client jar for  the microservice in my big project.

If i use rest template I will need to add the pojos  for request and response etc. My senior developer is insisting on using rest template but I don't quite like that approach.

Can someone suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the client jar for the microservice in my big project". How does that help you getting data from the microservice? at the end you are making a Rest call right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to facilitate usage of client rest calls, especially when more than one projects are involved, it is best practice to design a client wrapper that calls your desired endpoint as:

```
SystemApiClient client = new SystemApiClient();
List<Article> articles = client.getArticles("popular");
```

by designing such client wrapper, it's easy to make a jar file out of it and share it across you microservices. for ease of update you can also upload each new version on local nexus and easily get update on your project when a new one is available

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are using Spring in your whole project then you should go for `RestTemplate`. Just for calling the endpoint no need to pull another jar. Many times senior people / architect suggest to use unique libraries to maintain application standard and to avoid whole bunch of library offering similar functionalities.

Or if your application is developed in another framework or language you can use any `HttpRequest` supporting library. It doesn't matter what client side code you are using to access Rest endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

It's always preferable to have services called through rest end-points in service based architectures such as Micro-Services. But again the big question is what should you use - **JAR** or **WAR**. That highly depends upon type of projects and their architecture. In this case, it is MicroServices, Uncle Bob beautifully describes here - http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/09/19/MicroServicesAndJars.html